# AccesDeniedException, en java puro sobre Android 8.1 con AIDE

Tags: java

Tengo un programa en java puro que encripta archivos de un directorio en específico ( en este caso la sdCard ) y lo estoy ejecutando en Android Oreo 8.1 con el IDE para Android llamado AIDE ( no es una aplicación Android, es Java puro ) , y hay un bloque de código que elimina el archivo original pero tengo una excepción. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

CÓDIGO:

```
public static void deleteFiles( String file ) throws IOException
    {
    try
    {
        Files.deleteIfExists( Paths.get( file ) );
    }
    catch( NoSuchFileException e )
    {
        System.out.println("No such file exists");
    }
    }
```

Este es el error que lanza:

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   /storage/4A80-16E6/qwerty/test.mp4    at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)  at
>   encryptiondecryptionfile.ExecCrypto.deleteFiles(ExecCrypto.java:226)
>     at encryptiondecryptionfile.ExecCrypto.encrypt(ExecCrypto.java:97)
>     at encryptiondecryptionfile.ExecCrypto.main(ExecCrypto.java:34)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.aide.ui.build.java.RunJavaActivity$1.run(SourceFile:108)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

EL PATH DE LA CARPETA ES: `/storage/4A80-16E6/qwerty/test.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

tal y como te está diciendo la info del error, se trata de una **excepción del tipo AccessDeniedException**.

**Para empezar yo probaría a obtener información acerca de la excepción**: causa, etc...

Para ello puedes añadir el tratamiento para este tipo de excepciones:

```
catch( AccessDeniedException e1 )
    {
        System.err.println(e.getFile());
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(e.getReason());

    }
```

Así tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void deleteFiles( String file ) throws IOException
{
try
{
    Files.deleteIfExists( Paths.get( file ) );
}
catch( NoSuchFileException e )
{
    System.out.println("No such file exists");
}
catch( AccessDeniedException e1 )
    {
        System.err.println(e.getFile());
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(e.getReason());

    }
}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.

Comment: Esto fue lo que salió: /storage/4A80-16E6/qwerty/test.mp4
/storage/4A80-16E6/qwerty/test.mp4
null

Comment: Perdona, sutituye la repetida por esta System.err.println(e.getMessage());

Comment: Ya lo sustituí pero sale lo mismo

Comment: Es la SD Card del teléfono? Si es así, deberias comprobar que tienes permisos para borrar los archivos.

Comment: No tengo permisos, pero qué puedo hacer para tener los permisos

Comment: Hola Ivan, perdona que haya tardado en contestar. Para poder ayudarte necesitaría poder reproducir el problema y para ello necesitaría el código y el tipo de dispositivo que utilizas (móvil). Gracias